# nested jQuery function only fires once

Tags: jquery, asp.net, scope, updatepanel, nested-function

I am loading a function on document ready. It all works once. The page must be refreshed for it to work again.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    function resetChosen() {

        $('.chosen').val(' ').trigger('chosen:updated');
        alert('how many times will this work?');
    }

    $('#submitter').on('click', function (clickEvent) {

        setTimeout(resetChosen, 500);        

    })
})
```

I am basically trying to reset form fields with the class .chosen, after waiting 500ms. The alert is for debug.

It works, but only once. Why?

Thank you!

**UPDATE: More Detail**

I got looking at the HTML, and this button is in an UpdatePanel...

```
<form id ="form1" runat="server">

    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="true" EnablePageMethods="true" />
    <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="10000" OnTick="Timer1_Click" Enabled="true" />

    <div class="col-10 topRow">
        <div class="dispatchContainer">               
            <div class="col-1">
                <div class="dispatchBtnBox" style="display: block">
                    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel100" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="True">
                        <Triggers>
                            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="submitter" EventName="Click" />
                        </Triggers>
                        <ContentTemplate>
                            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="submitter" class="submitter" Text="Notify" OnClick="submitter_Click" />
                        </ContentTemplate>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

...presumably to keep the page from refreshing whenever it is clicked. Will this function need added to a Page Request Manager perhaps?

I have update the tags for my question.

Thank you!

**UPDATE 2 : Solution:**

I registered a scriptblock with the ScriptManager control on my code behind click event.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "submitterReset", "submitterReset", false);
```

Thank you!

Comment: It seems to be working for me https://jsfiddle.net/s6tcrhjw/6/

Comment: Yes, it is working! So what is the problem. Please post some details if possible.

Comment: @RezaMamun Thank you, I am not sure what more detail would be helpful. Basically when I click on the button element with ID="submitter", this function should fire every time, but it only does once, until I refresh the page. Both the val reset and alert only fire once after each page load. I will update above with some HTML...

Comment: @RezaMamun I believe I got this working with a ScriptManager control and registering a startup script block. I will update above...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at the markup for this and found my control was in an asp UpdatePanel. Registering the script with ScriptManager under my _Click fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you want, you can remove a lot of UpdatePanel markup. A few of the settings are the default settings so you don't need them. If you like to see them on the page that's fine, just leave them, but you can remove a lot of stuff, even the triggers -- anything inside an update panel that causes a postback is automatically a trigger.

Defaults: UpdateMode="Conditional"; ChildrenAsTriggers="True".

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel100" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="submitter" class="submitter"
            Text="Notify" OnClick="submitter_Click" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

[Remove things one at a time and test, just to be sure.]

Answer (score 0):

Settimeout runs the code once. Setinterval is what does the job. I've rewritten the code here for you. Try that and see if it helps.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function resetChosen() {
        $('.chosen').val(' ').trigger('chosen:updated');
        alert('how many times will this work?');
    }

    $('img').on('click', function (clickEvent) {`enter code here`
        setInterval(function () {
            resetChosen()
        }, 500);    
    })
})
```